# Wordpress Query Compare Meta Key to Page Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a shortcode that displays information on pages using a query of a custom post type I created. I want the query to display posts by comparing a meta field in the CPT to the title of the page that the shortcode is embedded on (i.e., the current page). Here's what I am working with so far:

```
   $post_name = get_the_title($post);
    
    $args = array(
       
        'post_type' => 'players',
        'author' =>  get_current_user_id(),
        'post_status' => array('registered', 'placed', 'paid'),
        'nopaging'=> true,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'league',
                'value' => $post_name,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
```

This retrieves the posts matching the criteria of post type, user ID, and post status. However, my `meta_query` does not affect the filtering of post information. I might just be pulling the `page_title` incorrectly. From all of my stack and google browsing, there are a number of ways to do so.

For reference, the comparison in the `meta_query` would be comparing a meta value of "Fall Outdoor Soccer," then comparing that to the page title of "Fall Outdoor Soccer Schedule." From my understanding of `LIKE`, that should work.

Any suggestions on the correct way to pull this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own issue. My code all worked fine to run the query and compare the meta field to the current page title. My issue is that I did not understand the `LIKE` statement. I understood it as comparing the `key` and seeing if it was `LIKE` the `value`. Instead, it was comparing the `value` and seeing if it was `LIKE` the `key`.

This made a huge difference in the query. I was trying to see if "Fall Outdoor Soccer Schedule" was `LIKE` "Fall Outdoor Soccer," which it is not. I resolved my approach to make sure the desired `value` is `LIKE` the `key`.